# How to change sandboxing flags of iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have an iframe in my aspx page. the code for that is:

```
<iframe style="height: 513px; width: 1071px" id="iframe1" sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups allow-forms" src="paymentprocess.aspx"></iframe>
```

the sandbox attributes are necessary for stopping the iframe page to take up entire window. after the payment the response page loads in iframe because of automatic redirection. I want to change the attributes of iframe thru javascript so that entire windows shows the response page. I am getting an error message in javascript console.

> the frame attempting navigation of the top-level window is sandboxed, but the 'allow-top-navigation' flag is not set.

I am using this code:

```
 if (top != self) {
     top.location = self.location;
 }
```

but that is throwing the above mentioned error in console.

Please someone help me how to change the attributes of iframe of parent window from child page (in this case confirmation page)

Comment: You have not included allow-top-navigation permission in the sandbox attribute of ur iframe?  www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_sandbox.asp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am assuming that the page you are loading this iframe within and the content you are loading inside the iframe are on different domains (Interpreted from paymentprocess.aspx). If this is the case you can not directly handle parent document because of cross origin policy. But still you can post message to the parent, handle this message in parent and set this extra flag in iframe attributes with set attribute.

Example code:

from iframe :

```
window.parent.postmessage("ChangeIframeAttributes", *);
```

inside your parent document:

```
window.addEventListener('message', function (event) {

    if (event.data === "ChangeIframeAttributes") {
      document.getElementById("iframeId").setAttribute("property","value");
    }

}, false);
```

In case you are on the same domain, you can access parent document with `window.parent.document`, fetch the element from document object and  `setAttribute`.

**Update**:

I have tried just setting the attribute using window.parent and attribute gets update but the problem still persists while changing top.location because *iframe is already loaded* and *attribute modification will not be effected unless nested browsing context of the iframe is navigated*.

**From w3c,**

http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-iframe-element.html

*These flags only take effect when the nested browsing context of the iframe is navigated. Removing them, or removing the entire sandbox attribute, has no effect on an already-loaded page*

*If the allow-scripts keyword is set along with allow-same-origin keyword, and the file is from the same origin as the iframe's Document, then a script in the "sandboxed" iframe could just reach out, remove the sandbox attribute, and then reload itself, effectively breaking out of the sandbox altogether.*

*Generally speaking, dynamically removing or changing the sandbox attribute is ill-advised, because it can make it quite hard to reason about what will be allowed and what will not.*

From my understanding, two workable options.

1. set the flag from beginning. (which is not a better way of doing it)
2. **use post message by sending url and setting window.location on parent.**

Pseudo code :

*on main window:*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function f()
{
    var eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
    var eventer = window[eventMethod];
    var messageEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";

    // Listen to message from child window
    eventer(messageEvent,function(e) {
        var key = e.message ? "message" : "data";
        var data = e[key];
        window.location = data;

    },false);
}
</script>
<body onload="f()">

<iframe id="iframeId" src="testiframe.html" sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups allow-forms">
</iframe>
</body>
```

*on iframe :*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var callParent = function () {

    window.parent.postMessage(" " + self.location, '*');

};
</script>
<button onclick="callParent()">set parent attribute<button>
```

Second approach i have tested with the above code and it works.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: hi Ramesh, actually confirmation.aspx & my parent page belongs to my own domain. So not an issue there. But I am trying to change the attributes of iframe tag of parent page from child page (i.e. confirmation.aspx). I am stuck there.

Comment: if because of lack of allow-top-navigation attribute you are not able to set the attribute as well though you are able to access window.parent (I guess you cannot set as this is sandboxed), then i think you should resort to post message as that's the only way to communicate between iframes or iframe and window object?

Comment: Hi Ramesh,Let me  r & d both solutions then I will give the answer

Comment: Better to change the title of the question to " how to change sandboxing flags of iframe" as this problem is more specific to iframe sandboxing.

Comment: Hi Ramesh, now I have one problem left. Now first the confirm page loads in iframe window, then it appears in the main window. Any was of preventing it from showing in the iframe ?

Comment: you can provide location href as about:blank to iframe. I think it should work. Because while loading any of the Url, chrome itself does that (first about:blank gets loaded and then the url we request gets loaded).